# Why are this operator's primes the Sophie Germain primes?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, prime-numbers

I was seeking a binary operator on natural
numbers that is intermediate between
the sum and the product, and explored this natural
candidate:

$$x \star y = \lceil (x y + x + y)/2 \rceil \;.$$

Then I wondered which numbers are prime with respect to $\star$,
i.e., only have one factoring.
For example,
$11 = 1 \star 10$ is prime but
$13 = 1 \star 12 = 2 \star 8$
is not.
Computing these $\star$-primes, I found they begin:

$$ 2,3,5,11,23,29,41,53,83,89,113,131,173,179,191, \ldots $$

I tried to prove there were an infinite number of
$\star$-primes, but then
discovered my primes are precisely the *[Sophie Germain primes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophie_Germain_Prime)*
(primes $p$ such that $2p+1$ is also prime),
and it is unknown if there are an infinite number of them.

Two questions:

> **Q1**. Why are the $\star$-primes as I defined
>   them precisely the Sophie Germain primes?

I see that factoring $xy + x + y$ to $(x+1)(y+1)-1$ reveals the connection, but
my argument for *iff* is not precise.
(Incidentally, the ceiling cannot be ignored:
replacing ceiling by floor results in different
"primes.")

> **Q2**. Is it possible to express the number of $\star$-divisors
>   of $n$ in terms of
>   a mixture of the number of
>   divisors $\tau(n)$ and the number of partitions $p(n)$?

For example,
here are the factors of $n=40$:
$$(1 \star 39), (2 \star 26), (3 \star 19), (4 \star 15), (7 \star 9), (8 \star 8) \;,$$
And so 40 has 11 $\star$-divisors:
$1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 15, 19, 26, 39 \;.$

I label this recreational because I'm sure this is like eating
candy for many of you!  Enjoy the snack!

**Addendum**. Incidentally, if $\star$ is defined using floor rather than
ceiling, then the $\lfloor \star \rfloor$-primes $>3$ are even numbers $n$
such that $n+1$ and $2n+1$ are (conventionally) prime.  I don't know if these primes
have been named, or if it is known whether there are an infinite supply.

Comment: Neat question (even if the solution was mostly elementary)!

Comment: Concerning the addendum; so $n+1=p$ is a prime such that $2p-1$ is prime. It is widely believed, but not proved, that there is an infinite supply of such primes. They probably do have a name, which can probably be retrieved by typing the first few into the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences. 

Comment: @Gerry: Thanks! Indeed they are http://oeis.org/A123998 .
A123998, "Numbers n such that 2n+1 and 4n+1 are primes." Apparently unnamed. But not unstudied!

Comment: Just came across this discussion from a link back by a more recent question and noticed that no one seems to know the name. Primes $p$ such that $2p-1$ is also prime are often referred to as Cunningham Chains of the First Kind of length 2 (kind of a mouthful). Sophie Germain primes are length 2 CCs of the second kind.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Q1. $p$ is $\star$-prime iff equation $xy+x+y=2p$ has no solution and $xy+x+y=2p-1$ has exactly one solution, i.e. $(x+1)(y+1)=2p+1$ has no solution (which is iff $2p+1$ is prime) and $(x+1)(y+1)=2p$ has only one solution $\{x,y\}=\{1,p-1\}$. This last holds iff $p$ is prime.

Q2. Why partitions?! The number of $\star$-divisors of $n$ equals $\tau(2n+1)+\tau(2n)-4$.

Comment: @Fedor: Brilliant! But perhaps we are using different conventions for $\tau$:
$\tau(79)=2$, $\tau(80)=10$, but this doesn't yield 10 $\star$-divisors for 40...

Comment: Very nice solution.  I fixed a typo.

Comment: The formula should be $\tau(2n) + \tau(2n+1) - 4$ using your conventions. This gives 11, which seems correct, since you missed the divisor 39.

Comment: @ndk: Thanks, Nick! Your corrections to the formula and to my counting resolve the confusion.

Answer (score 11):

In answer to your first question:

As you hinted at, it simplifies things to make the change of variable $x \mapsto x+1$.

Then the product becomes $x \star y = \lceil\frac{xy+1}{2}\rceil$. And we want to find $z$ that can't be expresed as $x \star y$ where $x,y > 2$.

Well that's equivalent to $z$ such that you can't solve $2z=xy+1$ with $x,y>2$, and also you can't solve $2z-1=xy+1$ with $x,y>2$.

The first condition is equivalent to $2z-1$ being prime, since the oddness of $2z-1$ makes the constraint on $x$ and $y$ irrelevant.

The second condition is equivalent to $z-1$ being prime, since it's saying that $2z-2=2(z-1)$ has no non-trivial factorizations beyond the obvious two involving the factor $2$.

Hence overall, we see that $z$ prime in the new sense $\Leftrightarrow$ $z-1$ Sophie Germain prime. Changing variables back, we get the answer to the original question.