# Sum of reciprocals of Sophie Germain primes

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

A prime $p$ is called a [Sophie Germain prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safe_and_Sophie_Germain_primes) if $2p+1$ is also prime:
[OEIS A005384](https://oeis.org/A005384).
Whether there are an infinite number of such primes is unsolved.
My question is:

> If there are an infinite number of Germain primes,
> is the sum of the reciprocals of these primes known to converge, or diverge?

Of course if there are only a finite number of Germain primes, the sum is finite.
And a lower bound on any infinite sum can be calculated. But it is conceivable
that it is known that the sum either converges or is a finite sum.
And maybe even an upperbound is known?

---

(My connection to this topic is via this question:
["Why are this operator's primes the Sophie Germain primes?"](https://mathoverflow.net/q/48638/6094).)

Comment: I believe one can show that the sum of their reciprocals must converge in the same way that the sum of the reciprocals of twin primes must converge.

Comment: Of course, if the answer is known, then it is known that the sum converges—or else we'd already know that there are infinitely many!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here is a general result.  For a sequence of nonnegative numbers $\{a_n\}$, let $A(x) = \sum_{n \leq x} a_n$. For example, if $S \subset \mathbf Z^+$ and we set $a_n = 1$ when $n\in S$ and $a_n = 0$ when $n \not\in S$, then $A(x)$ is the number of elements of $S$ that are $\leq x$.

Exercise: If $A(x) = O(x/(\log x)^r)$ for a positive integer $r$ and all $x \geq 2$, then $\sum_{n \leq x} a_n/n$ converges as $x \to \infty$ if $r \geq 2$ and $\sum_{n \leq x} a_n/n = O(\log \log x)$ for $r = 1$.

Example: if $f_1(T), \ldots, f_r(T)$ are polynomials with integer coefficients that fit the hypotheses of the Bateman-Horn conjecture (twin primes are $f_1(T) = T$ and $f_2(T) = T+2$, while Sophie Germain primes are $f_1(T) = T$ and $f_2(T) = 2T+1$), then Bateman and Stemmler showed $60$ years ago that the number of $n \leq x$ such that $f_1(n), \ldots, f_r(n)$ are all prime is $O(x/(\log x)^r)$, where the $O$-constant depends on $f_1, \ldots, f_r$.
Therefore if above we take $S$ to be the $n \in \mathbf Z^+$ such that $f_1(n), \ldots, f_r(n)$ are all prime and define $a_n$ to be $1$ or $0$ according to $n \in S$ or $n \not\in S$, then the exercise above says the sum of all $1/n$ for $n \in S$ converges if $r \geq 2$.

So for any sequence of pairs of primes $p$ and $ap+b$ that are expected to occur infinitely often ($p$ and $p+2$, or $p$ and $2p+1$, or $\ldots$), the sum of $1/p$ for such primes converges.

That the sum of the reciprocals of the twin primes converges indicates that this summation is the wrong thing to be looking at.  We want a strategy to prove the infinitude of twin primes, and that suggests a better sum.  The Bateman-Horn conjecture predicts the number of $n \leq x$ such that $f_1(n), \ldots, f_r(n)$ are all prime is asymptotic to $Cx/(\log x)^r$ where $C$ is a positive constant depending on $f_1, \ldots, f_r$, and if $A(x) \sim cx/(\log x)^r$ as $x \to \infty$ for some $c > 0$ then $\sum_{n \leq x} a_n(\log n)^{r-1}/n \sim c\log\log x$. Therefore we expect (but have never proved) that the sum of $(\log p)/p$ over prime $p \leq x$ such that $p$ and $p+2$ are prime should grow like $c\log\log x$ for some constant $c > 0$, and a similar asymptotic estimate (for a different constant $c$) should hold for the sum of $(\log p)/p$ over all prime $p \leq x$ such that $p$ and $2p+1$ are prime.

Comment: Thank you for that explanation. I did not know of the Bateman-Horn conjecture.

Comment: Shouldn't Schinzel be mentioned here, too?

Comment: @paulgarrett  I didn't because I am writing about quantitative issues, which Schinzel's Hypothesis H is silent about.

Answer (score 24):

Googling "sum of reciprocals of Sophie Germain primes" brings up the very recent paper:

*Wagstaff, Samuel S. jun.*, Sum of reciprocals of germain primes, J. Integer Seq. 24, No. 9, Article 21.9.5, 10 p. (2021). [ZBL1482.11122](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1482.11122).

[Here's a link to the paper on the journal's website.](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL24/Wagstaff/wag4.html) In particular, Wagstaff proves that the sum of the reciprocals of the Sophie Germain primes is between 1.4898 and 1.8027.

Comment: Thanks. I should have found that reference myself.

Comment: The paper *is* on the journal's website. I've edited your answer with the link (and with a citation formatted by the "cite" function).

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thanks. When I looked at the JIS website yesterday, it didn't have links to 2021 or 2022 papers. Although maybe my browser was using a cached version of that webpage from an earlier visit.

Comment: As the general advice goes, https://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: @AsafKaragila that's a cool site :)